# How to add a colour palette to b/w image?

Tags: image-processing, 8-bit

I have noticed in some tile based game engines, tiles are saved as grayscale or sometimes even black or white, and the colour is then added through storing a 'palette' along with it to apply to certain pixels however i've never seen how it knows which pixels.
Just to name a few engines i've seen use this, Notch's Minicraft and the old Pokemon games for Gameboy. This is what informed me of how a colour palette is used in old games: [deconstructulator](http://benfry.com/deconstructulator/)


From the little i've seen of people use this technique in tutorials it uses a form of bit-shifting however i'd like to know how that was so efficient that it was next to mandatory in old 8-bit consoles - how it is possible to apply red, green and blue to specific pixels of an image every frame instead of saving the whole coloured image (some pseudo-code would be nice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The efficient thing about it is that it saves memory. Storing the RGB values usually requires 24 bits (8 bits per channel). While having a [palette](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_color) of 256 colors (requiring 256*24 bits = 768 bytes) each pixel requires just 8 bits (2^8 = 256 colors). So three times as many pixels can be stored in the same amount of memory (if you don't count the needed palette), but with a limitied set of colors obviously. This used to be supported in hardware so the graphics memory could be more efficiently used too (well this is actually still supported in modern PC hardware but almost never used since the graphics memory isn't that limited anymore).

Some hardware (including the Super Gameboy supported by the first Pokemon games) used more than one hardware palette at a time. Different sets of tiles is mapped to different palettes. But the way the tiles are mapped to different palettes is very hardware dependent and often not very straight forward.

The way the bits of the image is stored isn't always so straight forward either. If the pixels are 8 bits it can be an array of bytes where every byte simply is one pixel (as for the classic VGA mode used in many old DOS games). But the Gameboy for example uses 2 bits per pixel and others used 4, that is 2^4 = 16 colors per palette. A common way to arrange the bits in memory is by using [bitplanes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_plane). That is (in the case of 16 color graphics) storing 4 separate b/w images. But the bitplanes can in some cases also be interleaved in different ways. So there is no simple and generic answer to how to decode/encode graphics this way. So I guess you have to be more specific what you want pseudo code for.

And I'm not sure how any of this applies to Minicraft. Maybe just how the graphics is stored on disk. But it has no significance once the graphics is loaded into graphics memory. (Maybe you have some other feature of Minicraft in mind?)

Comment: Why would a colour use 24 bits? each channel is 0-255 so one byte each, 12 bits. Also I said Minicraft not Minecraft, easy mistake.

Comment: One byte is 8 bits: 8*3 = 24 bits. (Corrected to Minicraft, instead of Minecraft.)

Comment: Oh, silly me thinking 4-bit was a byte all this time.. The feature of Minicraft I was thinking about is that it loads from a compressed image of shades of grey, and maps pre-defined colours into the right places, is that done through bit operations or this "one byte per pixel" method you say? (does it have a name?)

Comment: The "one byte per pixel method" in this case just explains how the gray scale image is stored (on disk). If you have already gotten to the point where you can see it as a gray scale image the problem is already solved. What you are looking for might be "palette swapping"?